# SSH connections (port 22) refused after updating to Debian jessie

Tags: ssh, raspbian-jessie

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B and I updated it this afternoon from wheezy to jessie. I connect headlessly with VNC and SSH (usually the latter) because I play around with home LAMP and nodeJS servers.

Both worked fine before the upgrade. Since upgrading to jessie, SSH has been refusing my connections. The error is:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.3 port 22: Connection refused
```

So, I double checked the IP - no problem there. Then, I checked the hostname and users, both are correct. Then, I tried clearing my RSA keys on both the Mac and the Pi. No luck.

Finally, I checked to make sure the SSH daemon was actually running. And, it wasn't. So, I went through `raspi-config` and started SSH. I checked again with `service ssh status` and still got an empty response.

So, my question is: **why isn't the SSH service starting and could it have something to do with updating to jessie?**

If so, is my only option to reflash with wheezy?

Comment: jessie uses systemd style initialisation rather than whatever was used before.  I don't understand either of them.  It may have been broken by systemd.  However I upgraded to jessie some time ago and don't have that problem.  Have you done a full apt-get update/upgrade/dist-upgrade sequence?

Comment: This probably the result of the change sysvinit to systemd.

Comment: I recently upgraded to jessie, no issue with ssh (which was good, as it's a headless pi) ... the fact that you got an empty response from `service ssh status` is odd. If you decide to reflash with wheezy, try flashing to jessie instead - you'll lose eveything either way (use a different SD card so you don't) ... to reiterate, ssh on system updated to jessie runs fine